# geoCoder respsone loop - Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-geocoder

I am sending a lon/lat to google geocoder and getting a response data that trying to break into variabels, the response look like this:

[image]

this is my code:

```
getFormattedAddress(result) {
    const arrResult = result.address_components;
    let itemRoute = '';
    let itemLocality = '';
    let itemCountry = '';
    let itemPc = '';
    let itemSnumber = '';

    for(let address_item in arrResult) {
        if (address_item.types[0] == "route") {
            console.log(i + ": route:" + address_item.long_name);
            itemRoute = address_item.long_name;
        }

        if (address_item.types[0] == "locality") {
            console.log("town:" + address_item.long_name);
            itemLocality = address_item.long_name;
        }

        if (address_item.types[0] == "country") {
            console.log("country:" + address_item.long_name);
            itemCountry = address_item.long_name;
        }

        if (address_item.types[0] == "postal_code_prefix") {
            console.log("pc:" + address_item.long_name);
            itemPc = address_item.long_name;
        }

        if (address_item.types[0] == "street_number") {
            console.log("street_number:" + address_item.long_name);
            itemSnumber = address_item.long_name;
        }
    }

}
```

The error that I am getting is:
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

What I am missing?

Update, json outprint:

```
[
    {
        "long_name": "29-31",
        "short_name": "29-31",
        "types": [
            "street_number"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Götgatan",
        "short_name": "Götgatan",
        "types": [
            "route"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Södermalm",
        "short_name": "Södermalm",
        "types": [
            "political",
            "sublocality",
            "sublocality_level_1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Stockholm",
        "short_name": "Stockholm",
        "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Stockholm",
        "short_name": "Stockholm",
        "types": [
            "postal_town"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Stockholms län",
        "short_name": "Stockholms län",
        "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Sverige",
        "short_name": "SE",
        "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
        ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "118 26",
        "short_name": "118 26",
        "types": [
            "postal_code"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Theres no promise in your code. The error occured in a promise. The error is not in this question.

Comment: @Jonasw this what is looks like:  https://gist.github.com/shuma/2ef2ae41188b5dacb77d46a5d9df6de7

Comment: In one/all of the result doesn't contain `types` property ? can you check by `console.log('   ',address_item.types);`

Comment: @kumkanillam I checked, and they all have a types property.

Comment: Then I doubt error is coming from some other code you are not included in the question. could you please confirm error line no.

Comment: @kumkanillam the part of the code is here: gist.github.com/shuma/2ef2ae41188b5dacb77d46a5d9df6de7

Comment: Its not our job to dig trough your code, its yours to present it.

Comment: But probably theres no result in *results*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var  arr = [
    {
        "long_name": "29-31", "short_name": "29-31",
        "types": [ "street_number" ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Götgatan", "short_name": "Götgatan",
        "types": [ "route" ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Södermalm", "short_name": "Södermalm",
        "types": [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Stockholm", "short_name": "Stockholm",
        "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Stockholm", "short_name": "Stockholm",
        "types": [ "postal_town" ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Stockholms län", "short_name": "Stockholms län",
        "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "Sverige", "short_name": "SE",
        "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    },
    {
        "long_name": "118 26", "short_name": "118 26",
        "types": [ "postal_code" ]
    }
]

for (var i=0; i< arr.length ; i++) {
    if (arr[i].types.indexOf('route') > -1)
        console.log( 'route ' + arr[i].long_name );

    if (arr[i].types.indexOf('locality') > -1)
        console.log( 'locality ' + arr[i].long_name );
}
```

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake oops, I did it too quickly, please take a look at it now

Comment: I get this now TypeError: Cannot read property 'types' of undefined. But they are not undefined.

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake can you put this line above the `for loop` and include the output in your question  `console.log(JSON.stringify(arrResult, null, 4)'`

Comment: @SHUMAcupcake this should get you going in the right direction