# printing a string returns an error, but stringifying it with JSON first, doesnt

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, geocoding

im using geocoder with node to reverse look up some gps coordinates. This is the code im using:

```
var geocoder = require('node-geocoder');

var geo = geocoder({provider: 'google'});
geo.reverse({lat: 53.409702, lon: -1.429981}, function(error, result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0].city));  //Always prints sheffield
    console.log(result[0].city); //Always throws error
});
```

So something really strange is happening, Whenever i try to log the city, it will give the error: cannot read property 0 of undefined. This is something to do with the promise, i saw it on another SO post. I think its specific to geocoder.

Anyway, if i stringify it first, it will always print, in this case, sheffield. Since city's type is a string, why would it do this? Im fine with using it but im curious why stringifying a string works when it throws an error without

Comment: What is the expected type of `result[0].city`?

Comment: Did you try checking the `error` param?

Comment: the expected type is a string, yes ive tried with the error param, it doesnt get called because the error is with trying to access the string, after researching about the error, someone said to stringify it, and it worked

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you parse it back? i.e.: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0].city)))`

Comment: its printing 'Sheffield' when i try that Gerado

Comment: There's no way this can be happening. The argument to a function is evaluated before calling the function. So if `result` is `undefined`, it will be undefined in both function calls. You almost certainly have a typo in the one that's reporting an error.

Comment: Does `console.log(typeof result[0].city)` output string?

Comment: What do you get if you just log the individual parts, ie `result`,`result[0]`? Do you get the object you are expecting printed?

Comment: The error message means that `result` is undefined. What does `console.log(result);` show?

Comment: I promise you its happening haha, yes Steve thats outputting 'string'

Comment: If you want to send a comment to a specific user, put before `@` before their username. @GerardoFurtado won't see your comment if you just write Gerardo. There's automatic name completion.

Comment: console.log(result) always prints the array of objects with everything including city in it. Whats also weird, is that stuff like console.log(results[0].streetName) are printing fine, it just seems to be with city

Comment: If the error says "Cannot read property 0 of undefined", it has to be coming from `result[0]`, and `.city` is irrelevant. And it means that `result` is undefined. You must have mistyped that word.

Comment: Is the code that's getting the error really inside the callback function, or did you simplify it in the question?

Comment: I tried it locally on node v 9.11.1 I get both console statements fine, except when it errors out and I get a can't read property 0 of undefined, but never the first one without the second

Comment: thats the exact code im using, no spelling mistakes. Whats also weird if i print both at the same time, it throws an error but doesnt print sheffield first, this is hurting my brain

Comment: @generalhenry Does the stringify ever throw an error for you?

Comment: The line with the stringify does, but only ever the property 0 of undefined, adding an `if (error) { throw error }` would expose the real error.

Comment: I'm getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors, I suspect you're encountering the same

Comment: well now im getting the error that ive used my daily quota for this api, dammit

Comment: I just ran the same code with node v8.8.1 and I get the result without any error. The result I got is `"Sheffield"` and `Sheffield`.(With and without quotes.)

Comment: can you add a link to that SO post ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243302/geocoder-respsone-loop-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined  @Taki

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the error? I did some testing and it seems that the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error happens inconsistently. And when it did, I got the exact error as in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite "answer" your question ... but it might help shed a bit of light:

1. I modified your script as follows:

   ```
   var geocoder = require('node-geocoder');

   var geo = geocoder({provider: 'google'});
   var r = null;
   geo.reverse({lat: 53.409702, lon: -1.429981}, function(error, result) {
       r = result;
       var r2 = result;
       var r3 = {animal:"moose"};
       console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0].city));  //Always prints sheffield
       // console.log(result[0].city); //Always throws error
   });
   console.log("Done.");
   ```
2. I ran in the debugger and set a breakpoint at the console.log statement ("set breakpoint", line 9):

   ```
   node inspect tmp.js
   < Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/8bda9a9f-9735-4a5a-9cc2-9312e9ae2123
   ...
   debug> list(10)
   > 1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var geocoder = require('node-geocoder');
     2
     3 var geo = geocoder({provider: 'google'});
     4 var r = null;
     5 geo.reverse({lat: 53.409702, lon: -1.429981}, function(error, result) {
     6     r = result;
     7     var r2 = result;
     8     var r3 = {animal:"moose"};
     9     console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0].city));  //Always prints sheffield
    10     // console.log(result[0].city); //Always throws error
    11 });
   debug> sb(9)
   debug> c
   < Done.
   break in tmp.js:9
   ...
   ```
3. Printed out the value of "result":

   ```
   debug> repl
   Press Ctrl + C to leave debug repl
   > r3
   { animal: 'moose' }
   > result
   [ Object, raw: Object ]
   > result[0]
   { formattedAddress: '84 Holywell Heights, Sheffield, UK',
     latitude: 53.4100017,
     longitude: -1.4295795,
     extra: Object,
     administrativeLevels: Object,
     ... }
   ```

In other words, "result" is a complex object ... and console.log() appears to "do the best it can", to print out "whatever it can"

One solution:

1. Analyze the object in question (using the "repl" debugger command, Chrome Developer Tools, whatever).
2. "Tailor" your console.log.
3. For example: `console.log(result[0].formattedAddress);`.